# Starting a container with dynamic arguments from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to start a container with dynamic arguments from my lambda function. I'm using Fargate for container orchestration. So basically I'm trying to achieve something equivalent to this :

> docker run container-name arg1 arg2

We can set Environment Variables in Fargate but they are static. I want to pass these arguments dynamically while starting the container at the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send arguments to `docker run`, but you can send environment variables.

When defining your ECS Task params you can fill in  `containerOverrides` with your `enviroment vars`

```
var params = {
  taskDefinition: 'your-task-definition`,
  cluster: `your-cluster`,
  count: 1,
  overrides: {
   containerOverrides: [
    {
     name: 'container-name',
     environment: [{
        name: 'VAR NAME',
        value: value
     }]
    }]
  }
}

const result = await ecs.runTask(params).promise()
```

Then you can get the env vars and use them in your Docker `CMD` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RunTask (API) or run-task (CLI) in Lambda, you can use the '--overrides' to send in dynamic parameters like environment etc. Please check details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do something like this when you are calling ecs task through lambda function(python)

```
var params = {
  taskDefinition: 'your-task-definition`,
  cluster: `your-cluster`,
  count: 1,
  platformVersion='1.4.0',
  overrides={
        'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name':'container_image_name',
                'command': [script_name, arg1, arg2]

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can pass arg1 and arg2 as your data(json).
Be sure to add this in your dockerfile which is used to create your docker image

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["script_name"]
```